# Add values to Dictionary using loop

Tags: c#

I am building a small app that fill packs with matches, in the first function I set the number of packs and in the second function I "insert" the number of matches to the pack. When I try to run its keep telling me that "An item with the same key has already been added.", why is that and how I fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Drill
{
    public class NewMatchesGame2
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> dictionaryPack = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        public void manageGame()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("how many packs? : ");
            string p = Console.ReadLine();
            int packs = Convert.ToInt32(p);


            for (int i = 0; i < packs; i++)
            {
                dictionaryPack.Add(i, 0);
            }

            InitializeGame();
        }

        public void InitializeGame()
        {
            string s = dictionaryPack.Count.ToString();
            int Pa = Convert.ToInt32(s);
            int minPack = Pa / Pa;
            int dmin = minPack;

            while (Pa > minPack)
            {

                Console.Write("how many matches in pack number :" + minPack + " : ");
                string a = Console.ReadLine();
                int matchNumber = Convert.ToInt32(a);
                int val = matchNumber;

                for (int x = 0; x < minPack; x++)
                {
                    dictionaryPack.Add(minPack , matchNumber);
                }
                minPack++;

                /// Print(matchNumber);
                /// computerPlay(matchNumber);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this? `int minPack = Pa / Pa;`

Comment: You're gonna have to explain what's going on in the first 4 lines of `InitializeGame`. You're converting the count to string, converting it back to int and dividing it by itself (resulting in 1)?

Answer (score 0):

In both your functions `manageGame` and `Initialize`, you use same `dictionaryPack`.

And when you insert `dictionaryPack.Add("KEY","VALUE")`, the key should be unique. Obviously you not using unique values.

You are trying to update the packs. But using Add method instead!!

Comment: cant figure it out yet. :( is there an update method for it?
like: dictionaryPack.????(key,value)